# Проект перестал видеть ресурсы .resx

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, resources

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Гл[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Внезапно проект перестал видеть ресурсы.Не могу даже дизайнер формы открыть(если не удалить ресурсы из формы). От чего это может быть?
Пробовала перезапускать проект и студию, но без результано, если открыть изображение в ресурсах оно отображаеться, а когда  пытаюсь добавить через pictureBox не отображает изображения

Comment: зачастую подобное происходит при переименовании, переопределении.